# Software Design: Calculating distance to a location in Server or App?

Tags: android, mobile, gps

I am new to mobile development and I undertook some freelance work. Now I am required to display a page with top N nearest places (businesses registered with us).

I am wondering what the best way of going about this is, from my experience it would seem that I would want to do this calculation in my back-end server.

I have a NodeJS server, however, it seems the server will be concurrently doing a lot of other work just verifying JWT tokens and what not, I have seen that android provides a method to easily do these calculations (Location). I have also read that there are some google API's one could use.

The idea I have is that I can pull my places with their lat, long from my database then the user sends lat,long and my server calculates top N results and sends to user.

What would you recommend and why? 
Thanks!

Comment: THis is opinion based without a lot more info.  But you should probably be looking at GIS enabled databases and using the built in location functionality of the DB.  Posgres has GIS support with PosGIS

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: Server.

But why?

The job of the server to make it so no one can use the app who is not authorized to do so. Thats one of many jobs anyway. However, you should send your location to the server, the server makes the API call, and returns the N closest locations.

You take that response, parse it, and fill in a view as you would like. With the server doing the heavy lifting, you can then also keeps track of something better, like how many calls, which calls, location of calls, etc etc.

Comment: Awesome, I'll go with server. Also, I found the geo-nearby library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/geo-nearby). Basically now I'll just create a Geo dataset from my database and use this library to obtain results.